# set image for navigation title is not properly working in landscape

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I used this following code to set image for navigation title but when i checked it on landscape the image is coming out of navigation bar.I tried resizing but its not working.thanks

```
UIImageView *image=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,45,45)] ;
    [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"titleimage.png"]];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:image];
```

Comment: How did you try resizing it?

Comment: i tried autosizing from inspector window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In landscape the navigation bar is 32 points high rather than 44. So, in both orientations your image view is too big really. But in landscape you should be replacing the image view with a new instance with a smaller frame height.

Comment: can you suggest me which size i can use to work in both landscape and portrait.I just want same like twitter.Thanks

Comment: So you would need to use the smaller height of 32.

Comment: i used 25*25 so its working fine in both landscape and portrait

Answer (score 1):

Resize or change the UIImageView size when device going to change orientation, implement this delegate method

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{
   //You can replace image view with new, or you can set the frame of already existing image view in here. height should be 32 for iPhone
}
```